# Setting 100% on a child of body overflows the page

Tags: css, flexbox

This is the css

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}

div.sections {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0, orange, gold);
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

where `#container` is a sibling of `div.sections`, both directly under the body tag.
The problem is `#container`'s height overflows the body by `div.sections`'s height.
I have no idea what is the problem here or if it is related to flex. I do know how to solve it with javascript, 
but I'd really like to see the solution in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to put a specific height value to your parent `div.sections` like `height: 500px;` and this will fix your problem. Thanks

```
div.sections {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 500px; /* Height Value as you want */
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0, orange, gold);
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```